# fulltext search on xml in SQL Sever 2008

Tags: sql-server, xml, full-text-search

It is a simple query, how to set-up fulltext search on xml column in SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 1):

```
USE AdventureWorks
SELECT  AdditionalContactInfo FROM Person.Contact WHERE
FREETEXT (AdditionalContactInfo,' phone')
```